# Laravel 5.3 redirect after authentication

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.3

I have a problem with Laravel 5.3 authentication. I want to redirect users after login. If I wanted to redirect all users to same route i know, I can change attribute `protected $redirectTo = 'mypath'`, but I want to redirect users, based on their type so I need custom logic. In the docs it sais, I should make

```
protected function redirectTo(){
  //my logic goes here
}
```

but my function keeps getting ignored. In the docs it sais, my function should override `$redirectTo` attribute, but even if i delete it, it still goes to default route ("`/home`"). If I change the attribute value it redirects me to correct path, but my function still gets ignored.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#included-authenticating

My Login controller looks like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    //protected $redirectTo = '/';
    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        return redirect('admin/home');
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

}
```

EDIT: If I name my function `authenticated()` instead of `redirectTo()`, it works as planned.

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
      return redirect('admin/home');
}
```

Comment: Where are you overriding the `$redirectTo` variable? I don't see anywhere in your code a value assigned to `$this->redirectTo`

Comment: Have you tried returning a string instead of a redirect object?

Comment: @yivi I did, i tried return "admin/home"

Comment: @dragos I deleted it. It doesn't make a difference if it is there or not. I edited my answer, so the commented part is $redirectTo variable.

Comment: Return a URL proper, not a route name.

Comment: @yivi, it is not a route name, it is a url. Actuallly, I figured out that if i rename function to authenticated() instead of redirectTo, it works as it should. Still don't know, why, would appreciate any explanation.

Comment: try overriding the property at constructor ? i guess it will work

Comment: Was literally working up this same question when I saw this.  I'm wondering now if the Docs has a typo and meant redirectPath()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel uses `RedirectUsers::redirectPath()` to get redirect path.

It only checks a property `redirectTo`.

If you want apply custom logic - just overwrite `redirectPath()` method in your controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    //protected $redirectTo = '/';
    public function redirectPath()
    {
        // ...
        // custom logic here 
        // ...

        return '/my/custom/url/here';
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

}
```

The same approach will work for `RegisterController` and `ResetPasswordController`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)